# How to create horizontal menu using json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, css

I have a json object like

```
var data = [
        {
        "parent": "Home",
        "child": [

                ]
        },
        {"parent": "Services",
        "child": [
                {"title":"Infrastruture"},
                {"title":"Development"}

                ]
        },
        {
        "parent": "Sector",
        "child": [
                {"title":"Recruitment Consultant"},
                {"title":"Change Management"},
                {"title":"Industrial Relations"}
                ]
        },          
        ]
```

I want to make a horizontal menu with respect to this json. I am new json object.So how can i do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes.. i did this using jq widgets.but there i used id. But i want the json like the above code mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get it done.

Markup

```
<ul id="nav"></ul>
```

JavaScript

```
var data = [
    {
    "parent": "Home",
    "child": [

            ]
    },
    {"parent": "Services",
    "child": [
            {"title":"Infrastruture"},
            {"title":"Development"}

            ]
    },
    {
    "parent": "Sector",
    "child": [
            {"title":"Recruitment Consultant"},
            {"title":"Change Management"},
            {"title":"Industrial Relations"}
            ]
    },          
    ];
$(function() {
    var nav = $("#nav");
    $.each(data,function(idx, obj){
        if(obj.child.length>0)
        {
            nav.append('<li><a href="#">'+obj.parent+'</a><ul id="'+obj.parent+'">'); //Create Parent menu and attach Child menu items list with ID same as parent menu name.
            var parent = $("#"+obj.parent); //Select this parent to insert child items.

            //Insert child menu items.
            $.each(obj.child, function(idx, childobj){
                parent.append('<li><a href="#">'+childobj.title+'</a></li>');
            });
            nav.append('</ul></li>'); //Close each tag.
        }
        else
        {
            nav.append('<li><a href="#">'+obj.parent+'</a></li>'); //No child menu items present, just create parent menu.
        }
    });
});
```

This could be semantically wrong since we've got so much of markup coupled with JS (not a good idea), but as long as structure remains the same, it is fine to do this way.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7KE2s/)

**P.S.:** I'm leaving you with the *styling* part. Hint: Provide classes along with markup in JS itself. ;-)

Comment: If i have another subchild field for recruitment menu..How can i integrate that?

Comment: @NithinViswanath: Then you'll have to add another `$.each` under new condition within `if` block, and that should be quite easy to do from above example.

Comment: @NithinViswanath: You're asking to add another child to your `data` JSON object or you want to know how to create another sub-menu from child menu item?

Comment: i know that..but how to create sub child menu?

Comment: @NithinViswanath: Dude!! as I said its pretty simple if you understood how above code in my answer works, but if you just want code to copy-paste then its not what SO is exactly made for.

Comment: @Kush- do you know about responsive design?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your json like a `Javascript Object`. You can do things like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    createHeaderLink(data[i].parent);
    createChildLinks(data[i].child);

}
```